# ImportError: No module named distutils.core

Tags: py2exe, distutils, enthought, canopy

I am trying to make an executable with python, py2exe using Enthought. And I'm sure there is no problem with my setup.py. 
But after running:python setup.py py2exe. There is an error look as below:
ImportError: No module named distutils.core
So, how can I solve the problem?

Comment: What's the version of Python?

Comment: It looks like below:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
    from distutils.core import setup
ImportError: No module named distutils.core

Comment: What version of Canopy or EPD? What version of python? The current version of Canopy is 2.1.3, directly available for Python 2.7 and 3.5, and available for Python 3.6 with an additional environment setup step. To update Canopy, please see ["Installing a new Canopy version"](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469570-Installing-a-new-Canopy-version).

Comment: Yeah...I've got the version of Canopy is 2.1.3.3542, and the version of Python is 2.7 , but the  problem  still exists.